# Convet byte[] in ASCII

Tags: c#, hex, byte, ascii

I'm trying to convert a byte[] in a string but need to use the HEX column of the ASCII table.

What i have:

```cs
*byte[] byteArray = new byte [] {41,56,41};

string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray, 0 ,byteArray.Length);*
```

Result expected:

```
AVA
```

What i got

```
)8)
```

If you could help me with this would be perfect. Thanks.

Comment: If you want hexadecimal numbers, use `0x41` instead of `41`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to write the input values in hex as such:

```
var byteArray = new byte [] { 0x41, 0x56, 0x41 };
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversions are correct. You are using *decimal* numbers to do the conversion, which translate to the Hexadecimal values `0x29, 0x38, 0x29`, which map to the characters that you see. You can get the correct values for the characters you want from any ASCII table. The Windows Character Map application is a good example.